# Unable to Disable a RadioSelect Widget Using Forms Class in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, radio-button

I have a form that contains a RadioSelect field. I am not able to disable this field in this form either in the init() method (<1>/<3>/<4>) and/or in the creation of the RadioSelect form element (<2>). There is one subclass to this form, but it does not use the radioButton field in question. I have been working on identifying what the issue is for the past 4 hours to no available. What could I have missed?

Below is a snippet of the code that I am using:

```
class ExampleForm (ParentForm1, ParentForm2, ParentForm3):

def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #<1>
    self.fields['radioButton'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
    #<3>
    #self.fields["radioButton"].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
    #<4>
    #self.fields['radioButton'].widget.attrs.update({'disabled':'disabled', 'readonly':'readonly'})
#<2>
radioButton = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Gender"),
                                               initial='M',
                                               required=False,
                                               choices=GENDER_LIST,
                                               widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"disabled":"disabled"}))
```

I am using Django 1.4.

Comment: How about `self.fields["radioButton"].widget.attrs = {'disabled':'disabled'}`

Comment: @karthikr, any other suggestions? Do you know why setting the attrs dictionary does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#<1>
    self.fields['radioButton'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
#<2>
    self.fields["radioButton"].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
#<3>
    self.fields["radioButton"].widget.attrs = {'disabled':'disabled'}
```

The above methods work in disabling the RadioSelect field. It turns out that a JavaScript script was removing the "disabled" attribute for the RadioSelect field.